Wall Disappears and Infinite Hallway Effect in Raycaster at Specific Player Angles and Positions
Problem
I'm working on a raycaster and have encountered a visual glitch that causes walls to disappear and creates an "infinite hallway" effect under certain conditions. This issue occurs when the player's direction is exactly perpendicular to a wall and the player's position coincides exactly with a grid line. Here are the specific conditions under which the bug appears:

Player Direction: The direction (in radians) is perpendicular to the wall.
Player Position: The position is precisely on a grid line.

When these conditions are met, the wall directly in front of the camera vanishes, and side walls extend into what appears to be an infinite hallway.The following two pictures illustrate the problem.


The source code is in C, I am only allowed to use the standard library <math.h>, therefore I wrote the vector functions on my own. The raycasting algorithm is heavily inspired by Lode Vandevenne's guide to Raycasting but I am using solely euclidean angles instead of a camera plane, since it was easier to understand for me.
I will provide the significant part of the source code below:
t_vec   angle_to_vec(double angle)
{
    t_vec   result;

    result.x = cos(angle);
    result.y = sin(angle);
    if (fabs(result.x) < 1e-5)
        result.x = 0;
    if (fabs(result.y) < 1e-5)
        result.y = 0;
    return (result);
}

t_vec   vec_add(t_vec a, t_vec b)
{
    t_vec   result;

    result.x = a.x + b.x;
    result.y = a.y + b.y;
    return (result);
}

t_vec   vec_scal_m(t_vec a, double scalar)
{
    t_vec   result;

    result.x = a.x * scalar;
    result.y = a.y * scalar;
    return (result);
}

t_vec_int   vec_int_scal_d(t_vec a, double scalar)
{
    t_vec_int   result;

    result.x = (int)(a.x / scalar);
    result.y = (int)(a.y / scalar);
    return (result);
}

t_vec   vec_inv(t_vec a)
{
    t_vec   result;

    if  (fabs(a.x) < 1e-3)
        result = (t_vec){0, 1};
    else if (fabs(a.y) < 1e-3)
        result = (t_vec){1, 0};
    else
    {
        result.x = 1 / a.x;
        result.y = 1 / a.y;
    }
    return (result);
}

double  deg_to_rad(double angle)
{
    return (angle * M_PI / 180);
}

int is_zero(double value)
{
    return (fabs(value) < 1e-10);
}

bool    vertical_gridline_hit(t_vec *d)
{
    return ((d->x < d->y && !is_zero(d->x)) || is_zero(d->y));
}

int is_tile_wall(t_cub3d *cub3d, t_ray *ray, t_vec_int map, int wall_type)
{
    ray->wall = cub3d->minimap->map[map.y][map.x];
    if (ray->wall == 0)
        return (ray->wall);
    if (wall_type == 1)
    {
        if (ray->dir.x > 0)
            ray->side = EAST;
        else
            ray->side = WEST;
    }
    else if (wall_type == 0)
    {
        if (ray->dir.y > 0)
            ray->side = SOUTH;
        else
            ray->side = NORTH;
    }
    return (ray->wall);
}

t_vec_int   stepping_direction(t_vec dir)
{
    t_vec_int   step;

    if (dir.x < 0)
        step.x = -1;
    else
        step.x = 1;
    if (dir.y < 0)
        step.y = -1;
    else
        step.y = 1;
    return (step);
}

t_vec   calculate_initial_offset(t_cub3d *cub3d, t_ray *ray, t_vec delta_dist,
        t_vec_int map)
{
    t_vec   p;
    t_vec   offset;

    p = cub3d->p->pos;
    if (ray->dir.x < 0)
        offset.x = (p.x - map.x * TILE_SIZE) * delta_dist.x;
    else
        offset.x = ((map.x + 1) * TILE_SIZE - p.x) * delta_dist.x;
    if (ray->dir.y < 0)
        offset.y = (p.y - map.y * TILE_SIZE) * delta_dist.y;
    else
        offset.y = ((map.y + 1) * TILE_SIZE - p.y) * delta_dist.y;
    return (offset);
}

void    dda(t_cub3d *cub3d, t_ray *ray, t_vec delta_dist, t_vec_int map,
        t_vec *distance)
{
    t_vec_int   step;

    step = stepping_direction(ray->dir);
    while (true)
    {
        if (vertical_gridline_hit(distance))
        {
            map.x += step.x;
            if (is_tile_wall(cub3d, ray, map, 1))
                break ;
            distance->x += delta_dist.x * TILE_SIZE;
        }
        else
        {
            map.y += step.y;
            if (is_tile_wall(cub3d, ray, map, 0))
                break ;
            distance->y += delta_dist.y * TILE_SIZE;
        }
    }
}

void    cast_ray(t_cub3d *cub3d, t_ray *ray)
{
    t_vec       delta_dist;
    t_vec       distance;
    t_vec_int   map;

    delta_dist = vec_apply(vec_inv(ray->dir), fabs);
    map = vec_int_scal_d(cub3d->p->pos, TILE_SIZE);
    distance = calculate_initial_offset(cub3d, ray, delta_dist, map);
    dda(cub3d, ray, delta_dist, map, &distance);
    if (vertical_gridline_hit(&distance))
        ray->distance = distance.x;
    else
        ray->distance = distance.y;
    ray->wall_hit = vec_add(cub3d->p->pos, vec_scal_m(ray->dir, ray->distance));
    ray->distance *= cos(cub3d->p->angle - ray->angle);
}

void    cast_fov(void *ptr)
{
    t_cub3d *cub3d;
    t_ray   ray;
    double  fov_rad;
    double  ray_inc;

    cub3d = (t_cub3d *)ptr;
    fov_rad = deg_to_rad(cub3d->p->fov);
    ray_inc = fov_rad / cub3d->width;
    cub3d = (t_cub3d *)ptr;
    ray.index = 0;
    while (ray.index < (int)cub3d->width)
    {
        ray.angle = cub3d->p->angle - fov_rad / 2 + ray.index * ray_inc;
        ray.dir = angle_to_vec(ray.angle);
        cast_ray(cub3d, &ray);
        render_vertical_stripe(cub3d, &ray);
        ray.index++;
    }
    render_sprite(cub3d);
}

Attempts to resolve the issue
I know this must probably be a classic 'off by one' problem. But I just can't find the significant condition or nail down the problem to solve the root cause.
As you can see I tried adding a lot of checks to check:

If double values are close to zero and then set them accordingly.
This only lead to a small vertical strip correctly rendered in the middle, but it does not prevent the hall effect.
I tried improving the typecasting from double to int
This lead to even bigger miscalculations during ray casting and rendering problems. So I reverted those changes.

Thank you :)

If you know the conditions that cause the problem it should be simple to create a [mre] including a main routine that we can run.

Thank you so much for your answer, but I read threw the description but I don't see a way on how I can create a minimal reproduce able example, since I hook into one specific library and since the project is quite big. I will try a little bit and let you know if I was able to build it.

Update: I was able to solve it. This problem appears when I am on a gridline and the offset of x or y is zero. The dda algorithm then exactly jumps over the wall. I now just add a little amount to the offset and it works. It's not that cleanest way, and I guess I am not addressing the root problem of 'not detecting the walls gridline' but it works. Thank you stark for the answer.
